# Test con envío de email en JMeter

Tags: apache

Tengo un **SMTP Sampler** en **JMeter** y al ejecutarlo, me salta este error:

```
2017-07-24 08:29:13,730 WARN o.a.j.p.s.s.SmtpSampler: Error while preparing message
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\apache-jmeter-3.2 (Acceso denegado)
  at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
  at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
  at javax.activation.FileDataSource.getInputStream(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
  at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
  at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1574) ~[mail-1.5.0-b01.jar:1.5.0-b01]
  at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:948) ~[mail-1.5.0-b01.jar:1.5.0-b01]
  at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.writeTo(MimeMultipart.java:538) ~[mail-1.5.0-b01.jar:1.5.0-b01]
  at com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed.writeTo(multipart_mixed.java:103) ~[mail-1.5.0-b01.jar:1.5.0-b01]
  at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
  at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
  at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1574) ~[mail-1.5.0-b01.jar:1.5.0-b01]
  at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1840) ~[mail-1.5.0-b01.jar:1.5.0-b01]
  at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1816) ~[mail-1.5.0-b01.jar:1.5.0-b01]
  at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.smtp.sampler.SmtpSampler.calculateMessageSize(SmtpSampler.java:192) ~[ApacheJMeter_mail.jar:3.2 r1790748]
  at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.smtp.sampler.SmtpSampler.sample(SmtpSampler.java:126) [ApacheJMeter_mail.jar:3.2 r1790748]
  at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:491) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
  at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:425) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
  at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:254) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
```

He cambiado de carpeta, he cambiado los permisos y no funciona.

Comment: Si alguien puede echarme una mano, estoy desesperada.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Ejecutando **qué**? ¿Qué código genera esos erroes?

Comment: Era al ejecutar un envío de email con SMTP sampler en JMeter. Ayer me funcionaba cambiando la librería de java mail; aunque me saltaba un error porque el antivirus que me bloqueaba la conexión.

Pero misteriosamente hoy sigue sin ir y salta el mismo error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Al parecer, enviar peticiones *SMTP* es un bug de *JMeter 3.2*. Doy la incidencia por **Cerrada**.

Comment: Esta respuesta parece de baja calidad. ¿Podrías agregar más detalles?